# Pre-fill Fastlink search box

Tags: yodlee

Was wondering if it is possible to pre-fill the Fastlink search box with a search term?
My use-case is I know the users Bank name before hand. To improve their experience wish to popup the Fastlink form with the name of their bank already entered.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the same result by passing in the siteId as a query parameter to the FastLink url.

eg: https://servername/appscenter/fastlinksb/linkAccount.fastlinksb.action?siteId=‌​2852

Answer (score 0):

As of now, this functionality is not available. While as an alternative you could explore the options if you can put the bank name of the consumer in the search using JS, that may help you to achieve the same goal.